# Button setOnClickListener is giving compilation error in ListFragment

Tags: android

I am trying to set setOnClickListener. This is my code.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MoviesFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);


        //Button button = (Button)outer.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        /*
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
               // do something
            }
        });
        */
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout outer = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.inc);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "i am null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Button button = (Button)outer.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v)
                  {
                     // do something
                  } 
        }); 


    }

}
```

But it is giving compilation error.

```
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})
```

Can anyone help me what is wrong here? How to fix?

Comment: Button button = (Button)outer.findViewById(R.id.button1); this is error

Comment: you have call like this  Button button = (Button)rootView .findViewById(R.id.button1);

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please check your imports,

and make sure you are imported

import the `View.OnClickListener` and you're good to go

Comment: Why did i get down vote? this is the right answer.

Comment: why do you think *this is the right answer* ?

Comment: Java basics... obvious: "java is strongly typed language". and you are passing another type of object as parameter. It is not even about Android sdk.

Comment: but he is trying to pass an instance of `OnClickListener` which is neither an instance of `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` nor an instance of `View.OnItemClickListener` (which does not exits).

Comment: İ just realized that i read the onItemClick listener  as OnClick listener. My mistake sorry. Now give my down vote back. İ have earned it. 

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to imports:

`import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`

Or use it directly:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(View v) {

      }
    });
```